# Getting Typeerror: can't concat str to bytes, when writing a test case to enter request files in django rest framework?

Tags: django, pandas, io, django-rest-framework, django-tests

I was working on a project where I can add a csv to upload shirts details to the database.

I wrote a viewset that takes shirt csv files input from request.data in django rest framework, and am writing a test case for the same. Though, while writing the test case, rather than creating a seperate csv file, I created a csv from pandas dataframe inside the test case, and converting it into TextIOWrapper to pass as request data. 
Doing this throws the following error:

```
  File "/Users/prasoon/projects/shirt_details/post_shirt_csv/tests/test_post_shirt_dataset.py", line 175, in test_shirt_dataset_post
    response = self.api_client.post(reverse('post-shirt-csv-dataset', kwargs={'session_id': self.session.id}), {'csv_files': [fp1, fp2]})
  File "/Users/prasoon/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 300, in post
    path, data=data, format=format, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "/Users/prasoon/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 212, in post
    data, content_type = self._encode_data(data, format, content_type)
  File "/Users/prasoon/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 184, in _encode_data
    ret = renderer.render(data)
  File "/Users/prasoon/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 920, in render
    return encode_multipart(self.BOUNDARY, data)
  File "/Users/prasoon/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 198, in encode_multipart
    lines.extend(encode_file(boundary, key, item))
  File "/Users/prasoon/projects/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 247, in encode_file
    to_bytes(file.read())
  File "/Users/prasoon/projects/venv/bin/../lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 320, in decode
    data = self.buffer + input
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

The thing works when I am opening a file and passing it instead of creating the string. It will be more clear below:

The tests file is:

```
class TestPostNewDataset(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = CurrentUserFactory()

        cls.test_data1 = {"no":[1,2,3],"colour":["Red","Blue","Gray"],"Size":["XL","L","M"],"Brand":["Nike","Polo","Adidas"],"Price":[800,600,1000]}
        cls.test_data2 = {"no":[1,2,3],"colour":["Black","Blue","Red"],"Size":["S","M","L"],"Brand":["Nike","Levis","Nike"],"Price":[2000,900,1000]}

        cls.test_df1 = pd.DataFrame(cls.test_data1)
        cls.test_df2 = pd.DataFrame(cls.test_data2)
        cls.session = CurrentSessionFactory(user=cls.user)

    def test_shirt_dataset_post(self):
        "Test request to post shirt dataset"

        fp1 = TextIOWrapper(StringIO(self.test_df1))
        fp2 = TextIOWrapper(StringIO(self.test_df2))

        response = self.api_client.post(reverse("post-shirt-csv-dataset", kwargs={'session_id':self.session.id}),{'csv_files':[fp1,fp2]})

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The corresponding views file is:

```
class CsvReadViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ShirtSerializer
    queryset = Shirt.objects.all()

    def addShirt(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        csvs = request.data["csv_files"]
        current_session = CurrentSession.objects.get(session_id=kwargs["session_id"])
        for shirt_csv in csvs:
            shirt_df = pd.read_csv(shirt_csv)
            for index,row in short_df.iterrows():
                s = Shirt(colour=row["colour"],
                          brand=row["Brand"],
                          size=row["Size"],
                          price=row["Price"],
                          created_in=current_session)
                s.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The interesting thing is that when the test case takes a seperate file as input, it works fine. That is if I replace test_shirt_dataset_post with following:

```
    def test_shirt_dataset_post(self):
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__ + "/../"), 'shirtcsv1.csv')) as fp1, open(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__ + "/../"), 'shirtcsv2.csv')) as fp2:
             response = self.api_client.post(reverse("post-shirt-csv-dataset",kwargs={'session_id':self.session.id}),{'csv_files':[fp1,fp2]})

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The expected result is the test case to work. But, here it throws an error as shown. The reason for adding TextIOWrapper is because the type of fp in `with open(....) as fp` is '_io.TextIOWrapper'.
Though, then it throws this error.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use io.BytesIO to send an encoded byte stream:

```
def test_shirt_dataset_post(self):
    "Test request to post shirt dataset"

    fp1 = BytesIO(self.test_df1.to_csv().encode('utf-8'))
    fp2 = BytesIO(self.test_df2.to_csv().encode('utf-8'))

    response = self.api_client.post(reverse("post-shirt-csv-dataset", kwargs={'session_id':self.session.id}),{'csv_files':[fp1,fp2]})

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: No, this wont work because you cant encode a pandas dataframe object in "utf-8" encoding.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with pandas, but I would imagine you could convert the dataframe to a string first, no? It's not like the dataframe object would survive uploading without some sort of conversion. Like you're using to_csv() in your solution below. I've edited my answer, the key part of which is using BytesIO instead of StringIO/ TexIOWrapper

Answer (score -1):

Found a possible answer.
So, one way to pass pass the string file as a file object is using NamedTemporaryFile.
So, the changed the code for test_shirt_dataset_post would be:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

def test_shirt_dataset_post(self):
    self.test_df1.set_index("id",inplace=True)
    self.test_df2.set_index("id",inplace=True)

    df1_csv_str = self.test_df1.to_csv().encode('utf-8')
    df2_csv_str = self.test_df2.to_csv().encode('utf-8')

    tp1 = NamedTemporaryFile()
    tp1.write(df1_csv_str)
    tp1.flush()

    tp2 = NamedTemporaryFile()
    tp2.write(df2_csv_str)
    tp2.flush()

    with open(tp1.name,'r') as fp1, open(tp2.name,'r') as fp2:
        response = self.api_client.post(reverse("post-shirt-csv-dataset", kwargs={'session_id':self.session.id}),{'csv_files':[fp1,fp2]})

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```